# remove elements in list while looping

Tags: java, loops, iterator

Assuming that I have a `List<<LogFormat>Log>` like this:

```
[Log(name = a, accessTime = 5),
Log(name = a, accessTime = 4),
Log(name = a, accessTime = 3),
Log(name = b, accessTime = 10),
Log(name = b, accessTime = 9),
Log(name = c, accessTime = 2),
...]
```

I want to left the max value of `accessTime` in every `name`, just like this:

```
[Log(name = a, accessTime = 5),
Log(name = b, accessTime = 10),
...]
```

but I don't know how many `name`s in the List, so I tried to wrote a loop:

```
for (LogFormat s : Log) {
  for (LogFormat t : Log) {
    if (s.getName().equals(t.getName())
        && s.getAccessTime() > t.getAccessTime()) {
    Log.remove(t);
    }
  }
}
```

But it seems that I can't use `.remove()` in a loop, how can I fix this?

Comment: You could use a for loop with an iterator, and use the iterator's remove method to remove the item.

Comment: It is super missleading that both class and list of objects have the same name - `Log`.

Comment: Sorry for misleading, I've fixed that @Amongalen

Comment: Yes, you should definitely read about java naming conventions and start using meaningful names s, t, Log, Log ... super confusing

Comment: And instead of removing things from a list, would it make more sense to simply iterate your list once and collect the maximum for each "name" in a new list?

Comment: Agree, removing element on list could be dangerous in the practice.
I would suggest you to use Map to store the name as key, and the max access time as the value

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'm trying to fix it with an iterator @GhostCat

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let me try to fix it with Map or iterator.@M.R.Murazza

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested loop with an index then subtract from the index when you remove something:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.size() - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < s.size(); j++) {
        if (...) {
            s.remove(j--)
        }
    }
}
```

You'll also need to factor in checking the other way around (e.g. if the first element needs removing).

However, I think the best solution here would be to use a Map, storing the max value for each log, if this would be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    static class Log{
        private int accessTime;
        private String name;

        Log( String name,int accessTime){
            this.accessTime = accessTime;
            this.name = name;
        }
        public int getAccessTime(){
            return this.accessTime;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "{ name = " + name +", accessTime = " + accessTime + "}";
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Log> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(new Log("a", 5));
        l.add(new Log("a", 4));
        l.add(new Log("a", 3));
        l.add(new Log("b", 10));
        l.add(new Log("b", 9));
        l.add(new Log("c", 2));     

        Map<String, Log> m = new HashMap<>();
        l.stream().forEach( log -> {
            String name = log.getName();
            int accessTime = log.getAccessTime();
            if(m.containsKey(name)){
                if(m.get(name).getAccessTime() < accessTime) {
                    m.put(name, log);
                }
            } else {
                m.put(name, log);
            }
        });
        List<Log> valueList = new ArrayList<>(m.values());

        System.out.println(valueList);
    }
}
```

Output:

> [{ name = a, accessTime = 5}, { name = b, accessTime = 10}, { name = c, accessTime = 2}]

Answer (score 0):

This **foreach loop** with colons is a syntactic sugar for iterator that has the "remove" functionality. So you basically need the access to the iterator if you want to use it this way:

```
List<Log> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Log("a", 1), new Log("b", 5), new Log("a", 4), new Log("b", 2) ));

        for (Iterator<Log> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                Log currlog = it.next();
                it.remove();
        }
```

In order to store the log name with max access time you could use an auxiliary hash map  and keep the max value per name, updating it if needed during the iteration

Answer (score 0):

I would turn the problem around. Your goal is:

> I want to left the max value of `accessTime` in every `name`

A [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) suits these requirements perfectly. The `name` will act as key, while the maximum `accessTime` will be the values of the map.

So, given the class:

```
class Log {
  String name;
  int accessTime;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getAccessTime() {
    return accessTime;
  }
}
```

And a list of `Log`s called `logs`.

You simply need to use the collector [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) with [`Math::max`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,int)) as the merge function:

```
Map<String, Integer> maxAccessTimeByName = logs.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Log::getName, Log::getAccessTime, Math::max));
```

`Math::max` makes sure that the maximum value is selected when a conflict occurs, that is the same key occurs at least twice.

Now you can just access the maximum access time by name:

```
int maxAccessTimeForA = maxAccessTimeByName.get("a");
```